# How to plot a stacked bar chart using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, bar-chart, stacked

I have 3 dataframes for yearly data (one for 2014, 2015 and 2016), each having 3 columns named, `'PRACTICE', 'BNF NAME', 'ITEMS'`.

BNF NAME refers to drug names and I am picking out 3 Ampicillin, Amoxicillin and Co-Amoxiclav. This column has different strengths/dosages (e.g Co-Amoxiclav 200mg or Co-Amoxiclav 300mg etc etc) that I want to ignore, so I have used `str.contains()` to select these 3 drugs.
`ITEMS` is the total number of prescriptions written for each drug.

I want to create a stacked bar chart with the x axis being year (2014, 2014, 2015) and the y axis being total number of prescriptions, and each of the 3 bars to be split up into 3 for each drug name.

I am assuming I need to use `df.groupby()` and select a partial string maybe, however I am unsure how to combine the yearly data and then how to group the data to create the stacked bar chart.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

This is the line of code I am using to select the rows for the 3 drug names only.

```
frame=frame[frame['BNF NAME'].str.contains('Ampicillin' and 'Amoxicillin' and 'Co-Amoxiclav')]
```

This is what each of the dataframes resembles:

```
PRACTICE |  BNF NAME |  ITEMS
Y00327 | Co-Amoxiclav_Tab 250mg/125mg | 23
Y00327 | Co-Amoxiclav_Susp 125mg/31mg/5ml S/F | 10
Y00327 | Co-Amoxiclav_Susp 250mg/62mg/5ml S/F | 6
Y00327 | Co-Amoxiclav_Susp 250mg/62mg/5ml | 1
Y00327 | Co-Amoxiclav_Tab 500mg/125mg | 50
```

Comment: In order to make plotting easier, you're probably going to want to combine the three dataframes into a single one. If you post a small subset of the actual data ( `frame.head(5).to_dict()` ) we'll be able to help you faster.

Comment: @DataSwede I'm assuming this is using pd.concat() ? Please see a snapshot of the dataframe layouts that I have added.

Comment: @DataSwede When I try this, the resulting bar chart is not stacked i.e it is like a standard bar chart with only one drug (Co-amoxiclav).. any ideas as to why? I added .fillna(False) to deal with any missing values - not sure whether this has something to do with it?

Comment: @DataSwede - this line of code..'frame=frame[frame['BNF NAME'].str.contains('Ampicillin' and 'Amoxicillin' and 'Co-Amoxiclav')] ' to select the 3 drugs is not working... any ideas how to select these 3 substrings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are likely going to be a few different ways in which you could accomplish this. Here's how I would do it. I'm using a jupyter notebook, so your matplotlib imports may be different.

```
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

df = pd.DataFrame({'PRACTICE': ['Y00327', 'Y00327', 'Y00327', 'Y00327', 'Y00327'],
                   'BNF NAME': ['Co-Amoxiclav_Tab 250mg/125mg', 'Co-Amoxiclav_Susp 125mg/31mg/5ml S/F',
                                'Co-Amoxiclav_Susp 250mg/62mg/5ml S/F', 'Ampicillin 250mg/62mg/5ml',
                               'Amoxicillin_Tab 500mg/125mg'],
                   'ITEMS': [23, 10, 6, 1, 50]})



Out[52]:
BNF NAME    ITEMS   PRACTICE
0   Co-Amoxiclav_Tab 250mg/125mg    23  Y00327
1   Co-Amoxiclav_Susp 125mg/31mg/5ml S/F    10  Y00327
2   Co-Amoxiclav_Susp 250mg/62mg/5ml S/F    6   Y00327
3   Ampicillin 250mg/62mg/5ml   1   Y00327
4   Amoxicillin_Tab 500mg/125mg 50  Y00327
```

To simulate your three dataframes:

```
df1 = df.copy()
df2 = df.copy()
df3 = df.copy()
```

Set a column indicating what year the dataframe represents.

```
df1['YEAR'] = 2014
df2['YEAR'] = 2015
df3['YEAR'] = 2016
```

Combining the three dataframes:

```
combined_df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], ignore_index=True)
```

To set what drug each row represents:

```
combined_df['parsed_drug_name'] = "" # creates a blank column
amp_bool = combined_df['BNF NAME'].str.contains('Ampicillin', case=False)
combined_df.loc[amp_bool, 'parsed_drug_name'] = 'Ampicillin' # sets the row to amplicillin, if BNF NAME contains 'ampicillin.'

amox_bool = combined_df['BNF NAME'].str.contains('Amoxicillin', case=False)
combined_df.loc[amox_bool, 'parsed_drug_name'] = 'Amoxicillin'

co_amox_bool = combined_df['BNF NAME'].str.contains('Co-Amoxiclav', case=False)
combined_df.loc[co_amox_bool, 'parsed_drug_name'] = 'Co-Amoxiclav'
```

Finally, perform a pivot on the data, and plot the results:

```
combined_df.pivot_table(index='YEAR', columns='parsed_drug_name', values='ITEMS', aggfunc='sum').plot.bar(rot=0, stacked=True)
```

[image: Stack Bar Plot]

Comment: When I try this, the resulting bar chart is not stacked i.e it is like a standard bar chart with only one drug (Co-amoxiclav).. any ideas as to why?

Comment: not sure whether it is something to do with adding .fillna(False)     ?

Comment: @LouiseStevens look at the data you're trying to plot. Are the other drugs present? You can look at the pivot table by deleting `.plot.bar(rot=0, stacked=True)`.

Comment: the problem is that this line of code does not select all 3 drugs correctly...'frame=frame[frame['BNF NAME'].str.contains('Ampicillin' and 'Amoxicillin' and 'Co-Amoxiclav')]' struggling to find a way to select these 3 strings. I have tried using '|' but this is only suitable for 2 arguments...

Comment: @LouiseStevens The three sections like: `amp_bool = combined_df['BNF NAME'].str.contains('Ampicillin', case=False)` and 
`combined_df.loc[amp_bool, 'parsed_drug_name'] = 'Ampicillin'` are what set the name. I broke them out to make it easier. Writing a single regex line to extract all three simultaneously makes my head hurt. My method took about 5 seconds to copy and pasting.